# How to read JSON data from a remote URL to a file in the local file store using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I want to hit a [remote URL](http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?callback=?&Filter=ProductId:14151&PassKey=t5sv9b3nvawhkljtlmegk8d6s&apiversion=5.0)

After googling, I decided to use `dojo.io.script.get`, as cross-channel calls are supported only in that. But, I keep getting the below error in my FF browser, but the correct response is also shown thr.

> syntax error
>   `http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?callback=%3F&Filter=ProductId%3A14151&PassKey=t5sv9b3nvawhkljtlmegk8d6s&apiversion=5.0`
>   Line 1
>
> ?({"Includes":{},"HasErrors":false,"Offset":0,"TotalResults":2,"Locale":"en_US","Errors":[],"Results":[{"TagDimensions":{},"TagDimensionsOrder":[],"AdditionalFieldsOrder":[],"Cons":null,"IsRecommended":null,"IsRatingsOnly":false,"UserNickname":null,"Pros":null,"Photos":[],"ContextDataValues":{},"Videos":[],"ContextDataValuesOrder":[],"LastModificationTime":"2012-01-10T09:10:33.000-06:00","SubmissionId":"ex7csdrwiorg3tbgpshbfcljd","TotalFeedbackCount":0,"TotalPositiveFeedbackCount":0,"BadgesOrder":[],"UserLocation":null,"Badges":{},"AuthorId":"shiji_sk","SecondaryRatingsOrder":[],"IsFeatured":false,"ProductRecommendationIds":[],"Title":"test title","ProductId":"14151","AdditionalFields":{},"CampaignId":null,"Helpfulness":null,"TotalNegativeFeedbackCount":0,"SubmissionTime":"2012-01-09T05:55:58.000-06:00","ContentLocale":"en_US","Rating":5,"RatingRange":5,"TotalCommentCount":0,"ReviewText":"test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test","ModerationStatus":"APPROVED","ClientResponses":[],"Id":"759582","SecondaryRatings":{},"CommentIds":[],"LastModeratedTime":"2012-01-10T09:10:33.000-06:00"},{"TagDimensions":{},"TagDimensionsOrder":[],"AdditionalFieldsOrder":[],"Cons":null,"IsRecommended":null,"IsRatingsOnly":false,"UserNickname":null,"Pros":null,"Photos":[],"ContextDataValues":{},"Videos":[],"ContextDataValuesOrder":[],"LastModificationTime":"2012-01-10T09:10:33.000-06:00","SubmissionId":"p6q13u5vgiqjfyk1xl5mktuvp","TotalFeedbackCount":0,"TotalPositiveFeedbackCount":0,"BadgesOrder":[],"UserLocation":null,"Badges":{},"AuthorId":"shiji","SecondaryRatingsOrder":[],"IsFeatured":false,"ProductRecommendationIds":[],"Title":"white review title","ProductId":"14151","AdditionalFields":{},"CampaignId":null,"Helpfulness":null,"TotalNegativeFeedbackCount":0,"SubmissionTime":"2012-01-09T04:16:40.000-06:00","ContentLocale":"en_US","Rating":5,"RatingRange":5,"TotalCommentCount":0,"ReviewText":"review for White Fabric Roll Arm Chaise & Contemporary Upholstered Armchair:\nGood one :-)","ModerationStatus":"APPROVED","ClientResponses":[],"Id":"759547","SecondaryRatings":{},"CommentIds":[],"LastModeratedTime":"2012-01-10T09:10:33.000-06:00"}],"Limit":10});

This is my script:

```
_invokeCrossSiteService: function(url, method, content, catEntryId, callbackFunction, appData, refresh)
{
    alert("in _invokeCrossSiteService..........................");
    if (content != null) {
        var temp = content;
        content = dojo.toJson(temp,false);
    }

     dojo.io.script.get({         
         // The URL to get JSON from Twitter         
         url: "http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json",         
         // The callback paramater         
         //callbackParamName: "callback", 
         // The content to send         
         content: {       
                    callback: "?",
                    Filter: "ProductId\:"+catEntryId, // Searching for catEntryId
                    PassKey: "t5sv9b3nvawhkljtlmegk8d6s",
                    apiversion: "5.0"
                },         
         // The success callback         
         load: function(resp) {

            alert("resp in _invokeCrossSiteService - "+resp);
            callbackFunction(status, data, appData);
         },
         error: function(resp){
             alert("in error - "+resp);
         }
    });
}
```

Can someone pls help me out here??

Comment: It seems you are using JavaScript and not Java. It looks to me that you are not passing a valid parameter for `callback` or that dojo is not replacing it properly. You should definitely read up about JSONP (which is what you are doing here).

Comment: I think better way is to use webservices to read remote content. read json using javascript is not a secure way. you can do it using any json parsing ways.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
callback: "?",
```

To

```
callbackParamName: "callback",
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
callback: "?"
```

You're using [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) (not just JSON). The way JSON-P works is by adding a `script` element to your page with the given URL; the script is then loaded from the remote endpoint, and (by JSON-P's general contract) it consists entirely of a call to the function name you provide, passing in a JavaScript object literal (JSON is a subset of object literal syntax).

So you need to give the endpoint you're calling the name of the function *it* should call once the resource has been loaded, as this is how JSON-P works. So for instance:

```
callback: "dataReady"
```

...where you have this global function on the page:

```
function dataReady(data) {
}
```

Note how what you get back is in the form `?(...)` — because the name you're giving the function is `?`.

I expect Dojo may well have a means of handling the function name and such for you, it may be worth looking at the docs to see if there's explicit JSON-P support. (There is in some other libraries.)